# Applying SAD on image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, templates, image-processing

Hello so I have an original image and I cropped a part of that image(template) and  wrote a code with SAD algorithim to detect on the original image the part i cropped (template) where it exists and draw a rectangle on it.

The code doesnt have any errors , but the rectangle draw doesnt match the template , so I guess the 'output ' variable is the problem can you please help me

```
I2=imread('img.PNG');
I2=rgb2gray(I2);
[r,c]= size(I2);

%padding the image
%padding
B = padarray(I2,[24 24],'replicate' ,'both');


%imshow(B);

%creating template
temp=imread('crop_img.PNG');
temp= rgb2gray(temp);
%imshow(temp)
size(temp)



output = zeros (size(I2));
K = size(temp)
x=1;
y=1;
for i = 25 :  r-24

    for j = 25: c-24

        %dif = temp -I2(i:i+47,j:j+47) ;
        K = imabsdiff(temp,B(i-24:i+24,j-24:j+24));

              output(i-24, j-24) = sum (K(:));




    end

end

%gettting min value in output
min_value = output(1,1)
for i=1 : r
    for j=1 :c
        if(output(i,j)<min_value)
           min_value=output(i,j);
           row=i;
           col=j;
        end    
    end
end
row
col
output(1,465)
output(6,200)

%draw rectangle on matching area
%Create the shape inserter object.

shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter;



%Define the rectangle dimensions as [x y width height].

rectangle = int32([row col 24 24]);

%Draw the rectangle and display the result.

J = step(shapeInserter, I2, rectangle);
imshow(J);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with image coordinates vs. matrix coordinates - you need to flip your row and column variables. Also, with `shapeInserter`, the coordinates are for the corner of the rectangle, so to make something centred on your output, you'd need something along the lines of:

```
rectangle = uint8([col-12 row-12 24 24]);
```

In MATLAB, it is usually not required to loop over every pixel of an image - it's much more efficient to work on the whole image at once. For example, you don't need a loop here:

```
min_value = output(1,1)
for i=1 : r
    for j=1 :c
        if(output(i,j)<min_value)
           min_value=output(i,j);
           row=i;
           col=j;
        end    
    end
end
```

This can be replaced by:

```
min_value = min(output(:));
[row,col] = find(output==min_value,1,'first');
```